# What is the operation in the stalks?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If we are using pre-sheaves as abelian groups, I know that the stalks are abelian groups also, but I would like to know what is the operation we use in this group.

$\overline {(U,s)} + \overline {(V,t)}=?$

Thanks.

Comment: Typo "pre-shelves" made me smile ;)

Comment: I guess $\overline{(U,s)}$ is the equivalence class of the section $s$ over $U$?

Comment: @DanielFischer it's the very first time I wrote this word lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One defines $\overline {(U,s)} + \overline {(V,t)}=\overline {(U \cap V,s|_{U \cap V} + t|_{U \cap V})}$, $~0 = \overline {(X,0)}$ and $-\overline{(U,s)} = \overline{(U,-s)}$.

More generally, if $(G_i)_{i \in I}$ is a [directed system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_system) of abelian groups (or any other algebraic structures) we can construct their [directed colimit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_system#Algebraic_objects)  (unfortunately often called direct limit, although it is NOT a limit). The underlying set is a suitable quotient set of the disjoint union of the underlying sets of the $G_i$, and the addition is given by $[i,s] + [j,t] = [k,G(\alpha)(s)+G(\beta)(t)]$, where $k \in I$ is such that there are morphisms $\alpha : i \to k$ and $\beta : j \to k$. The idea is just: We know how to add in a single group. So if we have two elements in different groups, just map them into a single group and add them there.

The stalk of a presheaf $F$ on $X$ at a point $x$ is defined to be the directed colimit of the directed system $(F(U))_{x \in U \in \mathrm{Open}(X)^{\mathrm{op}}}$.