# The equivalence of the definitions of stalks

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

The definition of direct limits is:

[image]

I'm trying to see how this definition works in the stalks:

The index $I$ is the open sets containing $x$ under the inclusion and the restrictions $\rho_{UV}:\mathcal F(U)\to \mathcal F(V)$ are the $f_{ik}$.

The $f_i$ are the maps where $s\in \mathcal F(U)$, $s\mapsto s_x\in \mathcal F_x$

I hope I'm right by now, I continue...

Then, In order prove the definition of direct limit is equivalent with the definition of $\mathcal F_x$, I have to demonstrate the diagram commutes using the definition of $\mathcal F_x$ using equivalence classes:

[image]

I'm struggling to prove the commutativity of the inner triangle $(f_j\circ f_{ij}=f_i)$, I need help in this part.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Which is your definition of $\mathcal{F}_x$? I would have said that $\mathcal{F}_x = \underrightarrow{\mathrm{lim}}_{x\in U} \mathcal{F}(U)$ just *by definition*.

Comment: @AgustíRoig please see the definition 1.3 in this pdf: https://www.math.lsu.edu/~hoffman/7280alggeom/lect22.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I see: you need to verify that, actually, definition 1.3 of [these notes](https://www.math.lsu.edu/~hoffman/7280alggeom/lect22.pdf) gives you a direct limit. Particularly, remarks 1.4 (2). Isn't it?

Well, I would say that this is by definition again.   :-)

You want to prove that $\tau_U = \tau_V \circ \rho_{VU}$, where $V \subset U$.

So, take any $s \in \mathcal{F}(U)$. Then, on one hand

$$
\tau_U(s) = [(s,U)] \ .
$$

(I'm omitting this subindex $\sim$: we all understand it.) On the other hand,

$$
(\tau_V \circ \rho_{VU})(s) = [(\rho_{VU}(s) = s_{\vert V}, V)] \ .
$$

By definition, two classes in $\mathcal{F}_x$ are the same if there is some $W \subset U\cap V$ such that, when restricted to this $W$ they coincide, right?

Ok, in our case, just take $W = V$. Of course, $s_{\vert V} = s_{\vert V}$.  :-)

Comment: lol, so easy, I can't believe I couldn't see this. thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Use the explicit construction of directed colimits (unfortunately often called direct limits, although they are not limits), which I have mentioned for example in your previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483346). An element of $\mathrm{colim}_{x \in U \text{ open}} F(U)$ is an equivalence class $[s]$, where $s \in F(U)$ for some $x \in U$ open, and we have $[s]=[t]$ for $s \in F(U), t \in F(V)$ iff there are maps $W \to U$ and $W \to V$ in the index category, i.e. inclusions $W \subseteq U$, $W \subseteq V$, such that $s,t$ have the same image in $F(W)$, i.e. $s|_W = t|_W$.

Comment: yes, it's obvious, I don't how I didn't see this, maybe because of my lack of experience in the subject. Thank you for help me again.